# Dynamic redirect from header.php

Tags: php

I have a structure like this:

```
myproject
    layout
        header.php
    user
        user.php
    index.php
    login.php
    logout.php
```

`header.php` is included in both `index.php` and `user.php`

`index.php` include code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '\layout\header.php');
```

`user.php` include code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '\..\layout\header.php');
```

In `header.php` I check if the user is logged in. If not logged in, The user is redirected to `login.php`:

```
if(!logged_in()){
    header('Location: ./login.php');
}
```

This works fine, If I visit `index.php`. But not working with `user.php`, As the URL becomes `/user/login.php` which doesn't exist.

And I can't change `header('Location: ./login.php');` to `header('Location: ../login.php');`, Because it won't work with `index.php`.

So how to make this dynamic or make the `header.php` directory the place where it goes back from?

Answer (score 0):

> Just replace

```
if(!logged_in()){
    header('Location: ./login.php');
}
```

> with this code, your issue will resolve.'

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['something']) || $_SESSION['something'] == ''){

 header("Location: ./login.php");
}
```

Comment: The issue is not with the condition. But the `header` redirecting to the right file